# Can I name the data store something other than App.Store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My problem domain has a `Store` model. Is there any way I can reserve `App.Store` for that and make some other class extend `DS.Store`? I see some code about `register('store:main')` but I don’t know that I can cleanly override it.

I can just rename `Store` if necessary, I’d just prefer to keep it the same name as on the existing backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can't, since `Store` is a reserved class name for `ember-data`. Furthermore when you do `App.Store = DS.Store.extend()` the property `Store` on your application namespace `App` will be looked up by `ember-data` which is expecting the name `Store`, if it's not there it doesn't work. IMO you are better served if you just rename your store model to something else to avoid name collisions.

Hope it helps

Comment: yeah, I eventually submitted to the will of the Ember Gods haha